# XSL apply-templates works with not matching elements too

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an input Xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Merge>
   <Object>
      <Value name="Name" type="Number">Hans</Value>
      <Value name="Vorname" type="Number">Peter</Value>
      <Value name="Gebort" type="Number">Germany</Value>
   </Object>
   <Data>
      <getGender>
         <get_Gender>male</get_Gender>
      </getGender>
   </Data>
</Merge>
```

And a xsl like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output media-type="text/xml" method="xml"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Features>
        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
        <Feature name="gender"><xsl:value-of select="//get_Gender"></xsl:value-of></Feature>
    </Features>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Value">
     <Feature name="{@name}"><xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of></Feature>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output is:

```
<Features>
   
      <Feature name="Name">Hans</Feature>
      <Feature name="Vorname">Peter</Feature>
      <Feature name="Gebort">Germany</Feature>
   
   
      
         male
      
   
<Feature name="gender">male</Feature>
</Features>
```

But why??
I'd like to have something like:

```
<Features>
      <Feature name="Name">Hans</Feature>
      <Feature name="Vorname">Peter</Feature>
      <Feature name="Gebort">Germany</Feature>
      <Feature name="gender">male</Feature>
</Features>
```

why is this random "male" in my output, i think is has something to do with the
`<apply-templates>` but i dont know why it behaves like it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are built-in templates that output text nodes through and with your `<xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>` you process all child nodes at that level recursively, so make that `<xsl:apply-templates select="Merge/Object"/>` or make sure you have an empty `<xsl:template match="get_Gender"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing something else than what the example shows, you could also drop the Template applications and traverse the nodes directly:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output media-type="text/xml" method="xml"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="/">
<Features>
<xsl:for-each select="Merge/Object/Value">
<Feature name="{@name}"><xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
</Feature>
</xsl:for-each>
<Feature name="gender"><xsl:value-of select="Merge/Data/getGender/get_Gender"/>
</Feature>
</Features>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```